# WooCommerce Widgets are not loaded

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've created a website using ElegantThemes Divi and added WooCommerce to it. For some reason the widgets from WooCommerce such as price filter and Layered Nav Filters are not loaded (not even visible in view source).

Has anyone encountered such a problem? (I am talking about a category page not item page - I know it is an issue).

Please note that other widgets I am placing below and above are visible.

Thanks

Comment: First try testing with a default theme to determine whether the problem is with your theme.

Answer (score 1):

A novice mistake, after reading quite a few posts on the matter I came to realize that WooCommerce widgets are only visible on the defaulted archive pages (i.e. domain.com/shop/product-category/) and do not work on any other page.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can have the Woocommerce widgets displaying by editing the default Woocomerce Shop page with this process:

- Go to Pages in your dashboard
- Edit the woocommerce shop page
- Click Edit with the Divi front end editor
- Add your layout with a Shop Module and the Sidebar module.